# How can I make a graphical plot of a sequence of numbers from the standard input?

Tags: command-line, graphics

If have a long text file and I want to display all the lines in which a given pattern occurs, I do:

```
grep -n form innsmouth.txt | cut -d : -f1
```

Now, I have a sequence of numbers (one number per line)

I would like to make a 2D graphical representation with the occurrence on the x-axis and the line number on the y-axis. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by occurrence? Do you mean how many times a particular number is found in the file? Or do you just want the actual value of the number on the x-axis and the line number that number was found on on the y-axis?

Comment: I mean by occurence simply in which order a pattern was found. e.g.: first time in line 400, second time in line 410 , third time in line 412 ...

Comment: Or you can redirect the stdout data through pipe to a custom python script. This will allow you immense amount of customization and flexibility in parsing, pre-processing and visualizing the data. Here is a tutorial on this I wrote to do exactly as you intend.
[link](http://manashpratim.com/plot-realtime-terminal-data)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could use [`gnuplot`](http://www.gnuplot.info/) for this:

```
 primes 1 100 |gnuplot -p -e 'plot "/dev/stdin"'
```

produces something like

[image]

You can configure the appearance of the graph to your heart's delight, output in various image formats, etc.

Comment: I have downloaded gnuplot and tried to test it by entering: seq 100 | gnuplot -p -e 'plot "/dev/stdin"' . strangely no graph appeared, but the exit code (echo $?) was 0 , so no error appeared either.

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred did you install `gnuplot` or `gnuplot-x11`? if the former, afaik it only provides file output (i.e. generating pdf, png etc. *files*) rather than interactive plots direct to the screen.

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred: What happens if you just do `seq 100 >seq.dat`, then run `gnuplot` interactively and at the prompt type `plot "seq.dat"` ?

Comment: @steeldriver I have an error `Failed to initialize wxWidgets.` with gnuplot-x11... Do I need to have one or the other? or can both `gnuplot` and `gnuplot-x11`be installed?

Comment: @nate thanks.  all i had in my head was "graphviz" which does not draw what i call graphs

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred it sounds like a terminal problem, see e.g. https://askubuntu.com/q/710783/383994

Comment: Very nice; append `notitle` to plot without the title.

Answer (score 15):

I would do this in `R`. You'll have to install it but it shouold be available in your distributions repositories. For Debian-based systems, run

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

That should also bring in `r-base-core` but if it doesn't, run `sudo apt-get install r-base-core` as well. Once you have `R` installed, you could write a simple R script for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
## Read the input data
a<-read.table(args[1])
## Set the output file name/type
pdf(file="output.pdf")
## Plot your data
plot(a$V2,a$V1,ylab="line number",xlab="value")
## Close the graphics device (write to the output file)
dev.off()
```

The script above will create a file called `output.pdf`. I tested as follows:

```
## Create a file with 100 random numbers and add line numbers (cat -n)
for i in {1..100}; do echo $RANDOM; done | cat -n > file 
## Run the R script
./foo.R file
```

On the random data I used, that produces:

[image]

I am not entirely sure what you want to plot but that should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: My Rscript v3.4.4 generates plots.pdf by default, regardless if using ggplot or plot.

Comment: @Vorac did you mean to comment on another answer? What does ggplot have to do with it? And why is the default output filename relevant?

Comment: On my debian system this subset of your script is enough  `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript;
args <- commandArgs(TRUE);
a<-read.table(args[1]);
plot(a$V2,a$V1,ylab="line number",xlab="value");` to generate an Rplots.pdf in the same directory.

Comment: @Vorac yes, of course. But I want to choose the output file name. And, more importantly show how it can be done so it can be scripted. Otherwise, each time you run an RScript, it will use the same name and overwrite the output of a precious run.

Answer (score 15):

If it might be that a very simple terminal printout would suffice, and that you could be satisfied by inverted axes, consider the following:

```
seq 1000   |
grep -n 11 |
while IFS=: read -r n match
do  printf "%0$((n/10))s\n" "$match"
done
```

The above charts an inverted trend on a 10% scale for every occurrence of the pattern *11* in the output of `seq 1000`.

Like this:

```
11
        110
        111
        112
        113
        114
        115
        116
        117
        118
        119
                  211
                            311
                                      411
                                                511
                                                          611
                                                                    711
                                                                              811
                                                                                        911
```

With dots and occurrence count it could be:

```
seq 1000    |
grep -n 11  | {
i=0
while IFS=: read -r n match
do    printf "%02d%0$((n/10))s\n" "$((i+=1))" .
done; }
```

...which prints...

```
01 .
02           .
03           .
04           .
05           .
06           .
07           .
08           .
09           .
10           .
11           .
12                     .
13                               .
14                                         .
15                                                   .
16                                                             .
17                                                                       .
18                                                                                 .
19                                                                                           .
```

You could get the axes like your example with a lot more work and `tput` - you'd need to do the `\033[A` escape *(or its equivalent as is compatible with your terminal emulator)* to move the cursor up a line for each occurrence.

If `awk`'s `printf` supports space-padding like the POSIX-shell `printf` does, then you can use it to do the same - and likely far more efficiently as well. I, however, do not know how to use `awk`.

Comment: Wow this creative, underutilized and probably sufficient for more cases than I realize.

Comment: Interesting. Can this be modified to read data from a csv file? (x,y)

Comment: @FractalSpace do you mean a comma separated array of graphical plot points? yes, i think one might work up a program to do that with `sort` and `sed` but you might as well use gnuplot.

Comment:  Thank you. Here's my TCP ping plot one-liner: `TIMEFORMAT='%3R'; while true; do t=$( { time nc -z 8.8.8.8 53 &> /dev/null; } 2>&1 ); s=$(echo $t | tr -d '.' | sed 's/^0*//'); printf "%0$((s))s\n" "$t"; sleep 0.1; done`

Answer (score 10):

Check the package [**plotext**](https://pypi.org/project/plotext/) which allows to plot data directly on terminal. It is very intuitive, as its syntax is very similar to **matplotlib**.

Here is a basic example:

```python
import plotext as plt
y = plt.sin() # sinusoidal signal 
plt.scatter(y)
plt.title("Scatter Plot")
plt.show()
```

[image: Scatter Plot]

You can also plot **bar plots**:

[image: Bar Plot]

and even **images**:
[image]

An example of plotting a **continuous data flow** is shown here:

[image: Data Stream]

It can be **installed** with

```
pip install plotext
```

or with:

```
pip install "plotext[image]"
```

to use plotext with images.

Answer (score 1):

Enhancing Nate's answer to have PDF output and to plot lines (requires the `rsvg-convert`):

```
| gnuplot -p -e 'set term svg; set output "|rsvg-convert -f pdf -o out.pdf /dev/stdin"; plot "/dev/stdin" with lines'
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible way, [it supports](http://pl0t.com) all kind of charts, not just line

```
plot="{chart:[line,{x: a},{y: b}],data:{a:[1,2,3],b:[2,4,1]}}"
curl -s http://pl0t.com/view.html | sed "s/{data}/$plot/" > play.html
open play.html
```

[image]

P.S. I'm the author of this tool.

Comment: Looks like your tool is down

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev yea, it's down, I'm done wasting my time wring open source programs :)